# Calculating the $\sum_{x=1}^\infty\left[\prod_{k=0}^s{s\choose k}x^k\right]^{-1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients, riemann-zeta, conjectures

> **Question:** If  $s \in \mathbb{N}$ is it true:  $\sum_{x=1}^\infty\left[\prod_{k=0}^s{s\choose k}x^k\right]^{-1}={\zeta\left[{s+1 \choose 2}\right] \above 1.5pt \prod_{k=1}^s{s \choose k}};$ where $\zeta\left[{s+1 \choose 2}\right]$ is the Riemann zeta function[$^1$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function) evaluated at the triangular numbers[$^2$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number) ?

I believe I can show the answer to the question is yes by way of inspection. I cannot get an actual **explicit calculation** that answers the question affirmatively - that is what I am asking for !

---

Solution to question by inspection: For short handedness I write $$\zeta_{\times}(s)=\sum_{x=1}^\infty\Bigg[\prod_{k=0}^s{s\choose k}x^k\Bigg]^{-1}$$ 
I computed a small list of values of $\zeta_{\times}(s)$ for small $s$:

\begin{array}{ l | l }
s & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\ \hline
\zeta_{\times}(s) & \frac{\zeta(3)}{2} & \frac{\zeta(6)}{9} & \frac{\zeta(10)}{96} & \frac{\zeta(15)}{2500} & \frac{\zeta(21)}{162000}& \frac{\zeta(28)}{26471025}\\ 
\end{array}

Inspection suggests that $\zeta_{\times}(s)$ has numerator equal to the Riemann zeta function at ${s+1 \choose 2}.$ The denominators of $\zeta_{\times}(s)$ can be written explicitly as $2,9,96,2500,162000,\ldots$; which appear to be the integer sequence A001142[$^3$](https://oeis.org/A001142). Listed in the reference section is the following paper by Lagarias: *Products of Binomial Coefficients and Unreduced Farey Fractions*.[$^4$](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.4145.pdf). Lagarias defines the unreduced Farey fractions[$^5$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farey_sequence) to be the ordered sequence of all reduced and unreduced fractions between $0$ and $1$ with denominator of size at most $s.$ Following Lagarias' notation: I write $G_s$ for the set of unreduced Farey fractions and let $|G_s|$ and $G_s^*$ denote the cardinality and the product of all elements of $G_s$ respectively. Lagarias shows the following results: $|G_s|={s+1 \choose 2}$ and $G_s^*=\prod_{k=1}^s{s \choose k}.$ I put everything together and get 
 $$\zeta_{\times}(s)={\zeta\big(|G_s|\big) \above 1.5pt G_s^*}$$

and I am done. $\blacksquare$

---

Source and motivation of the problem: Curiosity is the main driving source of the problem. Here it goes: If $x$ and $s$ are positive numbers I write $\zeta(s)$ for the Riemann zeta function evaluated at the number $s.$ For ease of typing  I write Pascal's Triangle[$^{6}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle) like this:
$$\text{ }\begin{matrix}
1&&&&\\
1&1&&&\\
\color{red}{1}&\color{red}{2}&\color{red}{1}&&\\
\color{blue}{1}&\color{blue}{3}&\color{blue}{3}&\color{blue}{1}&\\
1&4&6&4&1\\
\vdots
\end{matrix}$$
and recall that the first row in Pascal's triangle is numbered at $0$.  Now look at the second and third rows of the triangle, highlighted in red and blue respectively and observe: $\sum_{x=0}^\infty{ 1 \above 1.5pt \color{red}{1}+\color{red}{2}x+\color{red}{1}x^2}=\zeta(2)$ and  $\sum_{x=0}^\infty{ 1 \above 1.5pt \color{blue}{1}+\color{blue}{3}x+\color{blue}{3}x^2+\color{blue}{1}x^3}=\zeta(3).$ This observation shows that $\zeta(s)$ can be recovered from the rows of Pascal's triangle - in particular I can write $\sum_{x=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(1+x)^s}=\zeta(s).$ 
On the other hand using the binomial theorem[$^{7}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) allows me to compute $(1+n)^s$ explicitly with the formula: $\sum_{k=0}^s{s\choose k}x^k$ in which case after substitution: $$\zeta(s)=\sum_{x=0}^\infty\bigg[\sum_{k=0}^s{s\choose k}x^k\bigg]^{-1}$$ 
Now out of total curiosity I decided to swap the inner summation inside the big brackets and swap it out with a product, noting carefully that if I do that I need to shift the starting point in the outer summation to $1$ otherwise I would be dividing by zero. For short handedness I wrote $$\zeta_{\times}(s)=\sum_{x=1}^\infty\Bigg[\prod_{k=0}^s{s\choose k}x^k\Bigg]^{-1}$$ Numerical inspection suggested $$\zeta_{\times}(s) ={\zeta\left[{s+1 \choose 2}\right] \above 1.5pt \prod_{k=1}^s{s \choose k}}$$ I double checked my numerical hunch against Sloan's Database and encountered the paper by Lagarias. In Lieu of the fact that Lagarias has an explicit formulae for $\log G_s^*$ (see Lagarias paper or reference above for notation) I primarily became interested in computing $\log \zeta_{\times}(s).$ If I could answer the question affirmatively then I would know that $$\log \zeta_{\times}(s)=\log \zeta(|G_s|)-\log(G_s^*)$$

Comment: What is the source of this problem? It's quite an interesting sum.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\zeta_{\times(s)}
=\sum_{x=1}^\infty\Bigg[\prod_{k=0}^s{s\choose k}x^k\Bigg]^{-1}
$

Maybe I'm just being naive,
but since
$\prod_{k=0}^s{s\choose k}x^k
=\prod_{k=0}^s{s\choose k}\prod_{k=0}^sx^k
=G_s^*x^{s(s+1)/2}
$,
$\zeta_{\times}(s)
=\sum_{x=1}^\infty \dfrac1{G_s^*}x^{s(s+1)/2}
=\dfrac1{G_s^*}\sum_{x=1}^\infty x^{s(s+1)/2}
=\dfrac{\zeta(s(s+1)/2)}{G_s^*}
$.

Is there anything more to it than this?

Comment: That looks correct. I never thought to split the product !